# Outlook desktop users unable to click add-in UI in the taskpane

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-2019

I work on an add-in for Microsoft Outlook, and recently we’ve received reports from some users that they can no longer click on buttons in the taskpanes of add-ins.  Other add-ins, not just ours, have been affected by this issue.  Affected users can still open the taskpane without issue.  Our taskpane web view loads correctly, but then any clicking inside the taskpane has no effect.  We are not seeing console errors when this happens.

To help narrow things down further: we’ve seen this issue occur in Outlook 2019  and Outlook for Microsoft 365 MSO with Office 365 accounts so far.  We’ve seen this issue happen when the taskpane is opened from Compose view.  One affected user was using Outlook 2019 version 16.0.13127.20266 (32-bit).  Affected users have been running Windows 10, version 2004.  A team member was able to reproduce the bug by updating to version 2004, but the bug disappeared for them after a subsequent system update on the same version 2004.

Has there been any recent change to add-in taskpane behavior that could be causing this issue?

Comment: Could you provide additional details on repro steps, or check if you are seeing the issue with pinned addin, similar to the issue described here? github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1239

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the issue on my machine yet, but I've reviewed a video of the issue from a user.  It does look like this is likely the same issue as that GitHub bug.

Our user had the add-in pinned in read view, then clicked the reply all button to draft a reply (the add-in stayed opened since it had been pinned in compose view too), and then could not use the add-in.  Their behavior seems to match the repro steps and videos in that GitHub bug page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed, and the fix should be available in Windows build 19043.1266 or later. Note that it is the Windows Build that matters, not the Office build.

Answer (score 1):

We are seeing the same thing since updating to Windows 10 build 2004. For us, the add-in task pane freezes when the user tries to reply to an email (which is also compose view I guess).
Would be good to get an update on this as it is breaking the add-in for our users.

We are using Outlook Version 2009 (Build 13231.20200)
This is Outlook for Microsoft Office 365 MSO (16.0.13231.20146) 64 bit.

Comment: Just updated to Outlook Desktop version 2009 and this is still a problem. Can anyone confirm whether this is being investigated or has been confirmed as a known bug? thanks

Comment: Still no resolution to this issue. Does anyone have an update? thanks

Comment: The issue is fixed in all windows builds 21340 and later. Status on backports to older versions of Windows is still being decided. Note that it is the Windows Build that matters, not the Office build.